# How to declare a member of type tied to the member of another class?

Tags: c++

```
class A
{
   public:
   int a;
}

class B
{
   public:
   ????(A.a) a;
}
```

I want B.a to be the same type as A.a. `decltype` isn't correct, and I don't want to add a `typedef` to to class A.

Comment: "`decltype` isn't correct"? Says who?

Comment: My mistake was not using ::

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) like this:

```
class B
{
public:
    decltype(A::a) a;
};
```